# Parsing error of datatype.JSON field and interface in gorm query

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have three models

```golang
type ModelARepo struct {
    f1 string
    f2 int
    f3 string
}
```

```golang
type ModelB struct {
    f4 string
    f5 *string
    f6 any
    mAID *uuid.UUID
    BaseRepository
}
type ModelBRepo struct {
    f4 string
    f5 *string
    f6 datatype.JSON
    mAID *uuid.UUID `gorm:"foreignkey:mA;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    BaseRepository
}
```

```golang
type ModelABMapRepo struct {
    mAID uuid.UUID `gorm:"foreignkey:mA;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    mBID uuid.UUID `gorm:"foreignkey:mA;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}
```

Here f6 in ModelB is a datatype.JSON which is expecting `any` type in database for example it can be "TEST" or even ["TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3"]

I want to query ModelA and ModelB along with ModelABMap using joins
using

```golang
var res []map[string]interface{}
err := r.db.WithContext(ctx).
    Table("model_ab_map").
    Select(queryFields).
    Joins("INNER JOIN model_a ON model_a.id = model_ab_map.ma_id").
        Joins("INNER JOIN model_b ON model_b.id = model_ab_map.mb_id").
    Where(filter).
    Find(&res).Error
```

I want to fetch result in `map[string]interface` and I'm manipulating this map to get data however i want.

The result i get is

```golang
map[ma_id: , ma_f1: , ma_f2: , mb_f4: , mb_f5: , mb_f6: ]
```

Now the field f6 in ModelB in postgres DB i do

```golang
mapB := map[string]interface{}{
  "f6": res[0][mb_f6],
  "f4": res[0][mb_f4],
  "f5": res[0][mb_f5],
}
var mb ModelB
b, _ := json.Marshal(mapB)

json.Unmarshal(b, &mb)
```

Now if log `mb.f6` i get `""TEST1""` instead of `"TEST1"`.

How to parse the interface{} so i don't get Extra double quotes?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: You have to export struct fields (start them with capital letter).